# ¿Como puedo mandar el id de x producto al seleccionar el nombre de x producto en el spinner?

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

como puedo hacer que en un `spinner` que se muestran los nombres de x productos de un `JsonObject` que al momento de que seleccione, en ves de mandarme el nombre que me mande el id de ese producto.

Asi le coloco lo que quiero que muestre

```
private void getCategori(JSONObject j) throws JSONException {

      Iterator<String> keys = j.keys();
      while (keys.hasNext()) {
          // obtiene el nombre del objeto.
          String key = keys.next();
          Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key);
          JSONObject jsonObject1 = j.getJSONObject(key);


          cate.add(jsonObject1.getString(Categorias.TAG_NAME));
          cateid.add(jsonObject1.getString(Categorias.TAG_ID));
          opciones1 = new String[]{cate_name};

          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(prueba.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cate);
          scategory.setAdapter(adapter1);

          scategory.setPrompt("Categorias");
    }
```

y asi obtengo la posicion de lo que se selecciona

```
 private String getCatep(int position){
          String c="";
          try {
          JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
          jsonArray.put(returndatacategoria);

          JSONObject json= jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);

          c= json.getString(Categorias.TAG_ID);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return c;
  }
```

Comment: debes usar un Hashmap para almacenar el key y el value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712540/set-key-and-value-in-spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta implementar el click en cada elemento para poder hacer algo con el mismo, debajo del `ArrayAdapter` que creas te quedaria asi.

```
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(prueba.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cate);
      scategory.setAdapter(adapter1);

      scategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        String myCateId= cateid.get(i);
                        Log.e("CateId =",""+myCateId);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });
```

Primero, llenas el spinner con cate que son los nombres, y luego obtienes el ID con `cateid` de cada elemento que clicas

Comment: Gracias Gaston, eso era lo que me faltaba